# composing lenses using ramda

Tags: ramda.js, lenses

I'm trying to query the content of the nested object `coor`.

```
const data = [ 
   [ [{geo: {coor: [1,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [4,5]}}], {} ], 
   [ [{geo: {coor: [8,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [9,5]}}], {} ]
 ]
```

The result should be:

```
[[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[8, 2], [9, 5]]]
```

I use the following code to get this result:

```
const viewLens = R.view(R.lensPath(['geo', 'coor']))
R.map(R.map(viewLens), R.map(R.view(lensIndex(0)), data))
```

but I would like to compose a lens that can be used to map over `data`, something along the lines of:

```
const coorLens = R.compose(R.lensIndex(0), ..., R.lensPath(['geo', 'coor']))
```

that can be used like:

```
R.map(coorLens, data)
```

Does somebody know how to construct such a lens?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your plans for this lens? If it's just to view data, what you have, or some minor variant of it, seems fine.  If you want to use `set` or `over`, I think it would be substantially more complex.

Comment: I just want to `view`.

Comment: So the use of a lens is probably not essential. Something like `pipe(map(map(map(path(['geo', 'coor'])))), map(reject(isEmpty)), unnest)` might do what you need.  (And you can skip the `isEmpty` bit if the `{} ` entries meant "and more".  This function without that `isEmpty`  could be the getter for a lens, if you wanted to write a setter that set all coords at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a notion of a `mapped` setter that can be used to update values over functors in a lens construction, though this can only be used with `over`/`set` and not `view` (i.e. how do you fetch elements from something that can only be modified by `map`?)

There is also a notion of traversable optics that can focus on many elements rather than just one. This allows you to both update all elements under focus and providing you can state how you want the many elements to be combined in a single result, you can also view them. This won't give you the exact same structure though, as all focused elements will be combined together unlike the list of lists in your example.

Ramda itself does not offer this feature, though it can be found in the [ramda-lens](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-lens) library.

```js
const RL = ramdaLens

const data = [ 
  [ [{geo: {coor: [1,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [4,5]}}], {} ], 
  [ [{geo: {coor: [8,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [9,5]}}], {} ]
]

const coorLens = R.compose(
  RL.traversed,
  R.lensIndex(0),
  RL.traversed,
  R.lensPath(['geo', 'coor'])
)

console.log(
  "Combine all the focused elements in a list\n",
  RL.listOf(coorLens, data)
)

console.log(
  "Update all the focused elements\n",
  RL.over(coorLens, R.map(R.inc), data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/ramda-lens"></script>
```

I feel it's worth pointing out that unless you gain anything here by the ability to compose lenses, or to both view and update the focused elements then it may be simpler to avoid lenses with arguably more straightforward function composition like below.

```js
const data = [ 
  [ [{geo: {coor: [1,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [4,5]}}], {} ], 
  [ [{geo: {coor: [8,2]}}, {geo: {coor: [9,5]}}], {} ]
]

const fn = R.map(R.pipe(R.head, R.map(R.path(['geo', 'coor']))))

console.log(
  "Without lenses\n",
  fn(data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is usually where I get to with lenses, realising I don't need them at all.